# How to integrate Parse with third party user authentication service?

Tags: parse-platform, truevault

I am building a mobile app in which the users need to be authenticated via TrueVault which is a HIPAA compliant data store. TrueVault offers a REST API and generate an access token post basic authentication. They have endpoints to check token validity etc too.

We need to do 2 things:

1) Authenticate all users via TrueVault and store the auto generated TrueVault id in Parse to facilitate data mapping.

2) Setup an interceptor in Parse which verifies the access token with TrueVault before serving any protected resource.

What would be the simplest and most efficient way to implement the above? I have gone through the tutorial to add Third Party oAuth to the mobile apps, but TrueVault does not have oAuth in place yet and thus needs authorization requests via Basic Auth only. Also, would we need Cloud Code for the above or Custom Web Hooks?

Thanks
Sameer

Comment: My initial strategy would be to use Cloud Code with the NodeJS/Javascript wrappers available. Otherwise, making my own wrapper for Objective-C (or whichever client language) with the REST API from Truevault.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use retrofit, Gson(or jackson) and rxjava(rxAndroid) in order to handle all api calls, i made a quick overview to the api documentation and this libraries should work for this problem.

links:
https://github.com/square/retrofit

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Baniares, but I am looking for the best way to do this using the Parse service.